# Test if a list of variables are defined in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

My Makefile is based on multiple variables defined in a configuration file or `ENV` vars. My current solution is to test all of them manually:

```
NOGOAL = help clean distclean mrproper
ifeq ($(strip $(filter $(NOGOAL), $(MAKECMDGOALS))),)
VAR1 ?= $(error VAR1 undefined)
VAR2 ?= $(error VAR2 undefined)
VAR3 ?= $(error VAR3 undefined)
...
VARn ?= $(error VARn undefined)
endif
```

I would like to use a `foreach` loop instead:

```
ifeq ($(strip $(filter $(NOGOAL), $(MAKECMDGOALS))),)
TESTVAR = TEST1 TEST2 TEST3
$(foreach v, $(TESTVAR), $(eval $v ?= $$(warning Error: $v undefined)))
endif
```

Unfortunately `eval` doesn't work as I expected. Did I miss something?

Here a full test of my tests with 2 implementations of the tests. Even if `TEST3` is not defined I don't get any error

```
TEST1 = 1
TEST2 = 1
#TEST3 = 1   # NOT DEFINED


TESTVAR := TEST1 TEST2 TEST3

# First implementation
$(foreach v, $(TESTVAR), $(eval $v ?= $$(warning Error: $v undefined)))

# Second implementation
$(foreach v, $(TESTVAR), $(eval $(call TESTER,$v)))
define TESTER
ifndef $1
$(warning $1 not defined)
endif
endef

# Dummy rule
all:
    @echo Hello World
```

However, my first implementation works if I use `$(TEST3)` somewhere.

**EDIT**

Here I get no error but TEST3 is not defined:

```
~$ cat Makefile
TEST1 = 1
TEST2 = 1
#TEST3 = 1   # NOT DEFINED


TESTVAR := TEST1 TEST2 TEST3

# First implementation
$(foreach v, $(TESTVAR), $(eval $v ?= $$(warning Error: $v undefined)))

# Dummy rule
all:
        @echo Hello World

~$ make
Hello World
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're avoiding setting these variables if NOGOAL goals are set; surely you'd want to fail if any of these variables are not set and used in the NOGOAL goals as well?  Anyway, your first example works properly for me; if I don't set the variable I get `Error: TEST3 undefined`.  What exactly do you mean by _doesn't work as I expected_.  What happens?

Comment: @MadScientist I edited my question with the result I get. I don't have an error even if `TEST3` is not defined. I would like to avoid the tests to allow to type `make clean` if there is no configuration file because the rule `clean` does not depend on any external variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess I don't get it.  Your original version, that you say works the way you want it, will not print any warnings unless you USE one of the variables which is not defined.  Your first alternative with `foreach` works the same way: it will print a warning but only when you *use* the variable that's undefined.

If you want it that way, then testing for `clean`, etc. doesn't really make much sense since presumably those rules won't use the variables that are not defined so you won't get any errors (and if they *did* use the variables that weren't defined, presumably you'd want those rules to fail as well).

But in your second edit, you say that you want the make to fail immediately if the variables are not defined, regardless of whether or not they're used (in your last example you don't define `TEST3`, but you don't use `TEST3` for anything either so no warning is printed).  If that's what you want I don't see why you are assigning values to the variables with `?=` at all, or using `eval`.  Just write something like:

```
ifeq ($(strip $(filter $(NOGOAL), $(MAKECMDGOALS))),)
  $(foreach v,$(TESTVAR),$(if $($v),,$(error Error: $v undefined))
endif
```

(In this version you *do* need to check `MAKECMDGOALS` since it fails immediately on an unset variable).

Comment: Thank you. I was confused and I didn't get what I was doing :)